# Mysql group function error,wanted a second max value

Tags: mysql

Getting error on below mysql query as

> invalid group function use

```
SELECT logtime 
from  sgwebdb.audit_log 
where logtime < MAX(logtime) 
  AND userid = 'admin' 
  AND activity = 'LOGIN';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT logtime 
from  sgwebdb.audit_log 
where logtime < (SELECT MAX(logtime) FROM sgwebdb.audit_log ) 
  AND userid = 'admin' 
  AND activity = 'LOGIN';
```

---

### Update

For the second max value you can do this:

```
SELECT logtime
FROM 
(
   SELECT logtime 
   FROM sgwebdb.audit_log
   WHERE userid = 'admin' 
    AND activity = 'LOGIN'
   ORDER BY logtime DESC
   LIMIT 2
) AS t
ORDER BT logtime 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud.May i get a query for second max value for this?

Comment: @VimalSingh -  Add `ORDER BY logtime DESC LIMIT 1` will give you the second max

Answer (score 1):

I think thw upper query it's ok but:

```
SELECT logtime 
from  sgwebdb.audit_log L1
where logtime < (SELECT MAX(L2.logtime) FROM sgwebdb.audit_log L2 where L2.userid = L1.userid 
    AND L2.activity = L1.activity) 
    AND userid = 'admin' 
    AND activity = 'LOGIN';
```

I think you want max logtime for this couple of info user / activity.

Comment: i need second max value

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `group function (MAX)`in a normal query. This is incorrect. If you want to get only the second max value then

```
SELECT logtime 
from  sgwebdb.audit_log 
where logtime < (SELECT MAX(logtime) FROM sgwebdb.audit_log ) 
  AND userid = 'admin' 
  AND activity = 'LOGIN' limit 1;
```